# Is it a good programming practice to store java properties keys in ENUM for validation once application starts?

Tags: java, configuration, properties

Sample Java properties file which is read by the properties class

```
appl.component1.property1=value1

appl.component1.property1=value2
```

Custom class which extends the java.util.Properties class adding behavior to throw an exception when a  requested property is not available.

```
public class Configuration extends Properties {
    @Override
    public String getProperty(String key) {
        String value = super.getProperty(key);
        if (value == null) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException(MessageFormat.format(
                    "Value missing for key {0}!", key));
        }
        return value;
    }

}
```

Load properties file and retrieve the key value pairs for initial validation.

```
PropertiesExcep properties =  new PropertiesExcep();
properties.load("file://foobar");
for(PropertyKeys key: PropertyKeys.values()){
 properties.getProperty(key.getValue())
}
```

Enum using keys of properties

```
public enum PropertyKeys{
    PROP1("appl.component1.property1"),
    PROP2("app1.component1.property2");

private String value;

PropertyKeys(String in){
value = in_text;
}

public String getValue(){
return value;
}
}
```

Comment: The answer to this question depends on what problem you're trying to solve, and what sort of qualities you desire from the code.  Can you provide specifics?

Comment: Basically a Java Spark application which reads application configuration from an external properties file. I would want the application not to get to running state if any property is missing.

Comment: So the only specific requirement you have (other than the ability to have configuration properties) is that last comment at the bottom, which you didn't show any code for.

Comment: @RobertHarvey POST EDITED: I added in the code details to explain how exeption is thrown when a property is not found. The whole idea sums to storing keys in Enum and checking for each key in the loaded properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question would depend on a few things:

- **The biggest being:** Will you ever need to add/remove a key at run-time?

  If so, then an enum is unlikely to be the way to go - its values are supposed to stay constant, and this will lead to ugly code later on. Accessing the keys from  the `Properties` object directly would be a lot easier.
- How will you be using the keys?

  If you're going to be hard coding the keys in a lot,  this could save a quite a bit of time and effort. Otherwise it's just a waste of time.
- Is it worth having a variable for every key?

  If you're going to be using a lot of keys, it's going to become a mess and a pain to maintain.

To sum it up: it isn't an anti-pattern - there is no set rule, if it isn't going to save you time, clarify the code or cut down on difficulty - it's not worth doing. If it's going to hinder you in the future by becoming a pain to use - it's bad practice.

Comment: The applications that I am writing this for are long running(150 hrs or so big data applications) and my idea is to only save the time from reaching a point in the code during runtime when a particular variable is used and then the app fails due to its absence in properties file. Also, I do not need to add keys at run time and have less than 15 keys per application. What do you think?

Comment: @VishAmdi for missing properties, it would be useful to have another reference. If it will save you time, it's worth writing it - but I can't tell you if it's going to pay out. I don't see a problem in using the enum, though.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question, it is good to have validation because you externalize the application configuration and now application functions depends on configuration in the properties file. Yes, enum is an obvious choice to store the keys.

Any changes in keys of properties file shall impact the application functions. Validation will safe-guard our application against accidental changes in properties file.